# React Font Awesome Icons Bigger in Production

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome

Recently our react build has been producing different visual results.

Develop

[image: Develop build]

Production

[image: Production build]

as you can see the one icon on the far left is the correct size but the others are almost double. All these icons use Material UI Icon buttons with font awesome Icons

example of one of the icons

```
        <IconButton
          style={{ minWidth: '0px' }}
          color="default" 
          component={Button}
          onClick={openModal}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLink} />
        </IconButton>
```

Do you guys have any idea why the size might changing on production builds?

Edit #1

The Material UI classes .MuiButton-root and .MuiIconButton-root are changing priority between dev and prod

Edit #2

Inspecting Styles
Develop
[image]

Inspecting Styles
Production

[image]

As you can see the classes have different priorities between dev and prod.

Comment: browser dev tools should tell you exactly where they are getting sized

Answer (score 1):

You could try to force the size of the font awesome icon using fa-sm etc. and see if it's still happening.

like `<i class="fas fa-camera fa-sm"></i>`

Another possible workaround for that would be setting the size of the icon via custom CSS.

something like this for example:

```
.fa-camera{
  font-size: 0.73em;
}
```

Comment: That should work and I can do it as a work around but I'm more concerned why these material classes are changing priority.

Comment: @BOT_Billy do you use any custom css in your body-tag ? if so, please share your code then.